# How can I extract more than 1 match of the same pattern with regular expression?

Tags: python

For example, if I have 2 strings

```
[Mandzukic 18' (o.g.) Griezmann 38' (pen.) Pogba 59' Mbappe 65'; Perisic 28' Mandzukic 69']
```

and

```
[Samuel Umtiti 51']
```

How can I write a single regex that can extract [Mandzukic, 18, Griezmann, 38, Pogba, 59, Mbappe, 65, Perisic, 28, Mandzukic, 69] from the first string and [Samuel Umtiti, 51] from the second string?

This is what I have so far: (\w\s*\w+)\s(\d+) but I don't know how to get it to extract more than 1 instance of this pattern

Comment: how does you call your method for search?

Comment: someVariable = re.search("(\w\s*\w+)\s(\d+)", stringName)

Answer (score 1):

May be you this help,

```
    import re
    st = "Mandzukic 18' (o.g.) Griezmann 38' (pen.) Pogba 59' Mbappe 65'; Perisic 28' Mandzukic 69'"
    re.findall(r'(\w\s*\w+)\s(\d+)', st)
    # Output as: [('Mandzukic', '18'),
                  ('Griezmann', '38'),
                  ('Pogba', '59'),
                  ('Mbappe', '65'),
                  ('Perisic', '28'),
                  ('Mandzukic', '69')]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to find all the matches of a pattern. As for optionally matching a second word in your second sample input, you can put the word in a group with a `?` to make it optional:

```
import re
for s in "Mandzukic 18' (o.g.) Griezmann 38' (pen.) Pogba 59' Mbappe 65'; Perisic 28' Mandzukic 69", "Samuel Umtiti 51'":
    print(re.findall(r'(?:\w+\s+)?\w+\s+\d+', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['Mandzukic 18', 'Griezmann 38', 'Pogba 59', 'Mbappe 65', 'Perisic 28', 'Mandzukic 69']
['Samuel Umtiti 51']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1="[Mandzukic 18' (o.g.) Griezmann 38' (pen.) Pogba 59' Mbappe 65'; Perisic
 28' Mandzukic 69']"
import re
re.findall('(\w\s*\w+)\s(\d+)', s1)
[('Mandzukic', '18'), ('Griezmann', '38'), ('Pogba', '59'), ('Mbappe', '65'), ('
Perisic', '28'), ('Mandzukic', '69')]
```